# load uiviewcontroller container from another storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller, containers

when I drag a container into a uivewcontroller i get a new uiviewcontroller in red . 
[link](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=124899dashboard.jpg)

My question here how can i load this new view controller from another storyboard .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this :

```
UISoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifierOfSearchedViewController];
```

Comment: yes i can do it with that button in the red uiviewcontroller and i try it but in my case i want to load it without the use of this button .is  there any way to do this

Comment: Can you explain more? ok you don't want to use button so what are the other options? Which place exactly do you want to load it? You can use this method in anywhere but you need to use trigger (action) like button or something like that.

Comment: @user1645638 You can call it where you want in the code, specify more your question

Comment: it's a dashboard with different modules, each container contains the uiviewcontroller of the module , for my case i have a seperate storyboards for each module, so i want to display the root view of these storyboards ( of modules ) in the containers of the main storyboard.

Comment: In the viewDidLoad of dashBoard storyBoard loads all other UiviewController storyboards

Comment: how can i access containers of the dashboard storyboard?

Comment: @user1645638 : Drag IBOulet between the Storyboard and UIViewController to creat properties

Comment: i try it but i can't create embed segue between two storyboards , if you can give me an exemple or a tutorial describing that and i would be grateful .

Answer (score 0):

İf I understand truly;

You want to add another UIViewController in ContainerView therefore you can make it in storyboard with using segue that is **embed** property.

Don't use different storyboard if you want to do that. 1 storyboard many controllers just connect it as I said above.

Comment: the dashbord contains many modules , and it's very hard to collect them in the same storyoard if i understand you.